# How to check back with a college alumni if he doesn't get back you after promising to do so?

Tags: networking

I had a phone conversation with an college alumni and he told me that the would get back to me with some corporate contacts for a new job. Two weeks after the conversation, I heard nothing so I emailed him. He replied back asking for more time and to check again in a week if he doesn't get back to me.

A week passed and I did exactly that, but got no further responses. It's now been another week since then. I don't want to lose this corporate contact lead but I also don't want to irritate my connection with a weekly status check email.

What should I do? Do I email him one more time? If he doesn't respond then I give up? How should I word my email?

Comment: What's an alum?

Comment: @JaneS college alumni

Comment: It would seem that he wasn't really interested in doing anything for you and promised to email you in order to get rid of you. That's a common reaction. Instead of saying "I can't be bothered" which is impolite people will say "I'll email you back".

Comment: @sumelic I was always wondering about that but never bothered to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try emailing him in 2-3-4 weeks - sometime *after* the time he told you to email him. By this you will demonstrate patience, and also your desire to follow-up.

I would also find other ways of contact, maybe add him on LinkedIn, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You did the right thing to follow his instructions. I would either send 1-2 more emails a week apart or call him on the phone (but not both!). If he doesn't answer, he probably never will.

It might just be that he lost interest or forgot, but culture could also be an indicator; he might just expect you to *take a hint* and drop the matter entirely. Regardless, I wouldn't expect to hear back any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

It honestly sounds like it is time to move on. If you are asking him a detailed question and he's responding with a generic message, then it is most likely a hint to just drop it without directly telling you. Yes people are busy but they're not *that* busy where they can't get back to you in multiple weeks especially with something as simple as someone else's phone number.